# How to factorize this.

Tags: calculus, factoring, differential

We just started calculus and busy with limits. we were told that use a limit as long as it does not make the equation undefined. So the question is:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2x}{x^2+x}$

Now because the equation is undefined, my numerator is $2x$. How do I factorise that or what am I doing wrong and how do i correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x}{x^2+x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x}{x(x+1)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2}{x+1}$